# How to get accountID as part of Docusign connect xml notification?

Tags: docusignapi

We have configured custom connect listener endpoint in our springboot api. Keeping envelope details like Id, status to our database, by parsing xml notification received. We require to keep account Id as well.

Our App has to listen connect notifications **from multiple docusign accounts**. How we will differentiate xml notifications based on accounts, because xml has only envelope, document details. No account details mentioned.

Thanks,
Karuna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log into your DocuSign account, navigate to your Connect settings, edit your connect configuration, check the "Sender Account as Custom Field" box to include that data in the notifications. Then save.

All future notifications from that Connect instance will now contain AccountInformation in the XML body. Should look something like this:

```
         ...
         <CustomFields>
            <CustomField>
                <Name>AccountId</Name>
                <Show>false</Show>
                <Required>false</Required>
                <Value>{accountIDhere}</Value>
                <CustomFieldType>Text</CustomFieldType>
            </CustomField>
            <CustomField>
                <Name>AccountName</Name>
                <Show>false</Show>
                <Required>false</Required>
                <Value>{accountNameHere}</Value>
                <CustomFieldType>Text</CustomFieldType>
            </CustomField>
        ...
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. Clear solutions provided.

Answer (score 0):

A few options:
You can either put the accountID as a URL parameter when you set up the connect callback for each envelope/account so that you can get it on the other side.
Or you can add it as a custom field in the envelope and you get that information as well.
Custom fields are part of the envelope and are a secure way to store any meta-data you may need.
Both options are a bit more work for you, but that's what I can suggest at this time.

Comment: Thanks Inbar. Clear solutions provided.

Comment: Matt actually has a better way below

Comment: it's kinda the same way, but built-in

Comment: Sure, I will follow that way.